# excel VBA code works fine when run from excel but errors when ran from MS Access

Tags: excel, vba

the procedure below is opened from MS Access.
when it's run from Excel manually, all is well
however, when it's run from Access

```
Dim vrExcelApp As Object
Dim vrExcelWbk As Object

Set vrExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set vrExcelWbk = vrExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(vrCurPath & "Fedex.xlsm", True)
vrExcelApp.Visible = False
vrExcelApp.Run "MainProcedure"
vrExcelWbk.Close
vrExcelApp.Quit
Set vrExcelWbk = Nothing
Set vrExcelApp = Nothing
```

it gives me the wrong value for this line

```
vrPasteToCell1 = .Range("B" & vrCurRowNum).Value
```

the value of vrPasteToCell1  is supposed to be letter B, instead i get a 9, i'm pretty sure the 9 comes from here
vrPasteToRow1 = .Range("C" & vrCurRowNum).Value
[image]

another weird thing is, that it errors on 2nd iteration (this line doesn't error, things later in the procedure error because the value for vrPasteToCell1 is wrong

i don't even know how to troubleshoot this or what the issue can be and why it works when run from Excel

```
Public Sub MainProcedure()

    Dim vrFormattedDate As String, vrRunDate As Date, vrCompanyName As String, vrExcelFileName As String, vrFileExtension As String

    Dim vrReportPath As String, vrCurPath As String, vrQueryName As String
    Dim vrPasteToCell1 As String, vrPasteToRow1 As Long, vrPasteToCell2 As String, vrPasteToRow2 As Long, vrPasteFromCell1 As String, vrPasteFromRow1 As Long, vrPasteFromCell2 As String, vrPasteFromRow2 As Long
    Dim vrChartName As String, NoOfTotalsLines As Long, NoOfHeadersLines As Long, vrVariableRows As Boolean
    
    Dim vrExcelTemplate As String, vrNoOfRowsToAdd As Long, vrNoOfRowsInTable As Long
    Dim vrCurLastColumn As String, vrCurLastRow As Long, vrInsertRowsOnTemplate As Long, vrCountOfRowsInTable As Long, vrCurRowCt As Long, vrRowsOnTemplate As Long
    '
    '    Dim TableName As String, TemplateFileName As String, SheetToSelect As String
    '
    Dim vrCurRowNum As Long, vrLastRow As Long, vrFirstRowOfSection As Long, vrLastRowOfSection As Long, vrExcelSheetName As String, vrCurSheetName As String, vrPasteToFirstRowNum As Long, vrPasteToLastRowNum As Long
    Dim i     As Integer, vrCurCell As Variant, vrCurRange As Range
    Dim wbkM  As Workbook, wbkNewFile   As Workbook
    Dim wksExportSpecs As Worksheet, wksFilesToExportEMail  As Worksheet, wksCopyFrom   As Worksheet, wksCopyTo   As Worksheet, wks3  As Worksheet, wks4   As Worksheet, wks5  As Worksheet
    Dim rngCopyFrom As Range, rngCopyTo As Range, rngFilesToExportEMail As Range, rngInsertRowsTemplate As Range
    Dim vrOffset1 As Long, vrOffset2 As Long
    
        
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    vrCurPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    vrReportPath = vrCurPath & "Reports\"
    vrFileExtension = ".xlsx"

    fnCreateFolderIfDoesntExist vrReportPath
    
    Set wbkM = Workbooks("Fedex.xlsm")
    Set wksExportSpecs = wbkM.Sheets("qExportSpecs")
    Set wksFilesToExportEMail = wbkM.Sheets("qExportSpecsFedexConclusion")
    
    With wksExportSpecs
        vrCompanyName = .Range("A2").Value
        vrFormattedDate = .Range("D2").Value
    End With
    
    vrExcelFileName = vrCompanyName & "_" & vrFormattedDate & ".xlsx"
        
    Set wbkNewFile = Workbooks.Add
    wbkNewFile.SaveAs vrReportPath & vrExcelFileName
    Set wbkNewFile = Workbooks(vrExcelFileName)
                
    wbkM.Sheets("TConclusion").Copy After:=wbkNewFile.Sheets(wbkNewFile.Sheets.Count)
    wbkNewFile.Sheets("TConclusion").Name = "Conclusion"
    wbkM.Sheets("TMRCS").Copy After:=wbkNewFile.Sheets(wbkNewFile.Sheets.Count)
    wbkNewFile.Sheets("TMRCS").Name = "MRCS"
    
    If fnSheetExists2(Sheets, "Sheet1") Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
    End If



    vrCurRowNum = 2
    
    With wksFilesToExportEMail
        vrLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Set vrCurRange = .Range("A" & vrCurRowNum & ":B" & vrLastRow)
         
  
        For Each vrCurCell In vrCurRange
            If vrCurCell <> "" Then
                With wksFilesToExportEMail
                    vrQueryName = .Range("A" & vrCurRowNum).Value
                    vrPasteToCell1 = .Range("B" & vrCurRowNum).Value
                    vrPasteToRow1 = .Range("C" & vrCurRowNum).Value
                    vrPasteToCell2 = .Range("D" & vrCurRowNum).Value
                    vrPasteToRow2 = .Range("E" & vrCurRowNum).Value
                    vrChartName = .Range("F" & vrCurRowNum).Value
                    NoOfTotalsLines = .Range("G" & vrCurRowNum).Value
                    NoOfHeadersLines = .Range("H" & vrCurRowNum).Value
                    vrPasteFromCell1 = .Range("I" & vrCurRowNum).Value
                    vrPasteFromRow1 = .Range("J" & vrCurRowNum).Value
                    vrPasteFromCell2 = .Range("K" & vrCurRowNum).Value
                    vrPasteFromRow2 = .Range("L" & vrCurRowNum).Value
                    vrVariableRows = .Range("M" & vrCurRowNum).Value
                    vrNoOfRowsInTable = .Range("N" & vrCurRowNum).Value
                End With
 
                Set wksCopyTo = wbkNewFile.Sheets("Conclusion")
    
                If sheet_exists(vrQueryName) Then
                    Set wksCopyFrom = wbkM.Sheets(vrQueryName)
                
                    If vrQueryName = "qSummariesOverall" Then
                        With wksCopyFrom
        
                            .Range("B3:B4").Copy
                            .Range("C3:C4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

                            .Range("C3:C4").Copy
                            .Range("B3:B4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                        End With
                    End If
   
                    If vrVariableRows = True Then
                        If vrNoOfRowsInTable > 3 Then
                            If NoOfTotalsLines > 0 Then
                                vrNoOfRowsToAdd = vrNoOfRowsInTable - 3
                            Else
                                vrNoOfRowsToAdd = vrNoOfRowsInTable - 2
                            End If
                            With wksCopyTo
                                Do While vrNoOfRowsToAdd > 0
                                
                                    Set rngCopyTo = .Rows((vrPasteToRow1 + 1))
                                    rngCopyTo.Copy
                                    rngCopyTo.Offset(0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
                                    vrNoOfRowsToAdd = vrNoOfRowsToAdd - 1
                                Loop
                            End With
                        End If
                    End If
        
                    ' With wbkM
                    With wksCopyFrom
                        Set rngCopyFrom = .Range(vrPasteFromCell1 & vrPasteFromRow1 & ":" & vrPasteFromCell2 & vrPasteFromRow2)
                    End With
            
                    With wksCopyTo
                        Set rngCopyTo = .Range(vrPasteToCell1 & vrPasteToRow1 & ":" & vrPasteToCell2 & vrPasteToRow2)
                    End With
                        
                    rngCopyTo.Value = rngCopyFrom.Value
                        
                    If vrExcelTemplate <> "" Then
                        With wksCopyTo
                            Application.Goto Reference:=.Range("A1"), Scroll:=True
                        End With
                    End If
                                                                       
                End If
                '  End With
            End If
            wbkM.Worksheets(vrQueryName).Delete
            vrCurRowNum = vrCurRowNum + 1
            If vrCurRowNum > vrLastRow Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next vrCurCell
            
        wbkNewFile.Save
        wbkNewFile.Close
        Workbooks.Open vrReportPath & vrExcelFileName
        Set wbkNewFile = Nothing
        Set wksCopyTo = Nothing
        Set rngCopyTo = Nothing
        Set wksCopyFrom = Nothing
        Set rngCopyFrom = Nothing

        vrCurSheetName = ""
        
    End With
    
    wbkM.Worksheets("qExportSpecsFedexConclusion").Delete
    wbkM.Worksheets("qExportSpecs").Delete
    wbkM.Save
    
    Set vrCurCell = Nothing: Set vrCurRange = Nothing: Set wbkM = Nothing: Set wbkNewFile = Nothing: Set wksExportSpecs = Nothing: Set wksFilesToExportEMail = Nothing: Set wksCopyFrom = Nothing: Set wksCopyTo = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using late binding?

Comment: You need to use either `:A` instead of `:B` or `In vrCurRange.Columns(1).Cells` instead of `In vrCurRange`. Also, in the With statement in the loop, you need to use `vrCurCell.Row` instead of `vrCurRowNum` unless you have a `vrCurRowNum = vrCurRowNum + 1` at the end of the loop. In the long run, whenever you have the need of using a ton of variables for adjacent cells, you are missing the opportunity of using an array. Share the complete code in the For...Each Next loop to possibly see how.

Comment: Really need the full code to say what the problem is.  Seems like it may only accidentally work when run from Excel.  And how exactly are you running it from access?

Comment: sure, will post. and will post the part that runs it from access. this part is copied from other projects and works fine there. but thank you for helping, will edit the original now

Comment: posted the code, thank you both! about the A,B,CurRange, possible but this is copied from another project which runs from access with no issues. and yes, i do have that :) please look and let me know what you think. and yes, late binding everywhere i can. the code is a not perfect, work in progress

Comment: You have in your code still lines which are not fully qualified like     `Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled`,     `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` ,`Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Set wbkM = Workbooks("Fedex.xlsm")`, `Set wbkNewFile = Workbooks.Add`, `Set wbkNewFile = Workbooks(vrExcelFileName)` , `Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete` As long as you do not fix that your code is not really valid in MS Access.

Comment: @Storax - the code is in Excel, and called using `Application.Run`

Comment: If you make the Excel instance visible you might be better able to trouble-shoot.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I got it wrong.

Comment: @Storax - I originally thought the same thing

Comment: @Timm Williams: Thanks :-) 
Maybe it also helps not only to make the instance visible also to add a `Stop` at the beginning of the code in order to be able to step through it when running it from Access

Comment: it still errors :) and i can see which line gives me an issue, like i'm able to step through it, that's how i know what's happening. but i will make it visible, then i won't have to keep killing it through task manager to get it out of the memory. i think that's the only difference

Comment: With `For Each vrCurCell In vrCurRange` you're looping over (eg) "A2:B10" cell by cell, so it will run as A2, B2, A3, B3 etc.  But you increment  `vrCurRowNum` for each loop iteration.  Isn't that a problem?  @VBasic2008 made the same point above.

Comment: i give up. i did try redoing the loop but nothing worked to run it from access. if it works when run from excel, then i don't think it's the code. so, what i did was, add another column with the same data and now it works. however, it now glitches in a different spot, copies and pastes wrong values on 2 rows only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the stupidest mistake. So, posting my answer, in case someone else runs into this .

After exporting from Access, all tabs which were exported are selected in Excel, like, if you open the Excel file after export, you will see them all selected (for some weird reason, it also selects one of the tabs that weren't exported), and, before running the code, they have to be unselected (I do it by activating one of the tabs which weren't selected but maybe there's a better way)

The reason it worked when I ran the code from Excel was because I unselected the tabs before running code, I did it automatically, without thinking and didn't realize I was doing it